# Скрыть консоль без использования FreeConsole()

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Есть ли возможность как-то по другому скрыть консоль?

Comment: аналоги какие? для других осей или под винду, но тоже что бы закрывали консоль?

Comment: Под шиндовс надо

Comment: Можно ее не создавать...

Comment: @spais, зачем вам другой способ скрыть консоль?

Comment: @insolor иногда появляются косяки при использовании FreeConsole() и я хотел может есть какой-то другой метод убрать консоль

Comment: @spaia, ок, зачем вам убирать консоль? Какие именно косяки?

Comment: @insolor проблема почему-то с производительностью, когда я использую FreeConsole() моя программа потребляет 50% цп без нее 20%, а скрыть надо что бы не мешалась

Comment: @spais, вообще обойтись без консоли не вариант?

Comment: @insolor нет, так бы не задавал вопрос (

Comment: @spais, ну если так, то при такой постановке вопроса как сейчас я солидарен с VTT выше.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430801/8674428

Comment: Если у вас бесконечный цикл, то вам следует выполнять его с интервалом, я подозреваю вы делаете игру: попробуйте ограничить FPS или Выставить VSync в ней.

Comment: Как я писал в чате `Если IDE Visual Studio можно в настройках линковки выставить подсистему`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну для начала вы можете и не создавать консоль используя только функцию `winmain`

В случае если у вас Visual Studio, в настройках линковки `Project->Properties->Linker->System->Subsystem` указываете подсистему `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`. Консоль исчезла, а нагрузка будет минимальная.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно временно скрыть или отобразить консоль, можно использовать следующие функции:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void HideConsole()
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}

void ShowConsole()
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);
}
```

Источник: [C++ How do I hide a console window on startup? - ответ nikau6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430801/8674428)