# Открытие файла Си без консоли

Tags: c++, c, консоль

Всем привет! Сделал небольшую шалость. Программа заполняет рабочий стол файлами. Как мне сделать так, что бы консоль небыло видно? Я не использую никаких там WinApi и т.д. Чисто консольное приложение. Так вообще возможно сделать? Прошу не ругаться, я только учусь)

Comment: [Можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/860210), но **не нужно**.

Comment: Про "шалость другу" лучше уберите)) Как сделать, я ответил, но вообще-то  подобная информация элементарно гуглится.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В опциях компилятора или настройках проекта в IDE, которой вы пользуетесь, надо указать подсистему вашего приложения как WINDOWS, а не CONSOLE.

Для командной строки:
Если пользуетесь GCC (g++.exe), то компилируйте с опциями -Wl,-subsystem,windows
Для MS Visual C++ (cl.exe) аналогичные опции: /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Если пользуетесь Visual Studio, то там это делается в настройках приложения. Как именно, гугл подскажет лучше меня (я предпочитаю командную строку). Вот, например, одна из первых ссылок по запросу "visual studio set project subsystem": [https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~fliu/courses/cs447/tutorial1.html](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Efliu/courses/cs447/tutorial1.html)

Comment: В качестве дополнения - берем утилиту `editbin` из того же VS и с помощью команды `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` делаем таким любое уже скомпилированное приложение :)